# django downloading a file in development

Tags: django, django-views

I want to download a file in a django development project and I have an error...

Views.py:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
def download_track(request, zone_id, wId):

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = DownloadedTrackForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            path_to_file = '/var/www/tottrack/media/tracks/downloadedTracks/marc0.gpx'
            views.serve(request, path_to_file)
```

error:

```
'/var/www/tottrack/media/tracks/downloadedTracks/marc0.gpx' could not be found
```

The file exists in this folder...

Any idea?? Thanks!!

Comment: Just to confirm: if you place the line `print os.path.exists('/var/www/tottrack/media/tracks/downloadedTracks/marc0.gpx')` at the same point in the code (or log it), it prints True?

Answer (score 0):

Try [passing `document_root` to `serve` view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/static.py#L23). I'd separate your path into some static MEDIA_URL and path to file.